# Add offset to jQuery ScrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scroll, offset

Right now I am using a [ScrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com.ar/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) as demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39yUG). If you press the back/next button it will scroll you to the next post. The problem is that I have a fixed navigation bar and it blocks the posts. I did some research, both here and on the plugin author's blog and I learnt that you have to add an "offset" option. So I turned this

```
if (scroll) { 
            $.scrollTo(scroll, {
                duration: 750
            });
        }
```

into

```
if (scroll) { 
            $.scrollTo(scroll, {
                offset: -50
                duration: 750
            });
        }
```

However this just breaks the plugin and it stops working comepletely. I tried some other options as suggested by related posts but none of the methods worked.

/Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma between offset and duration

```
offset: -50,
duration: 750
```

I notice it works with 50, but with -50 you need to first scroll down a little. Needs a bit more work ;)

Comment: Didn't solve the problem but the offset did work now ) thanks